# docker exec via docker python SDK provides Group for directory as root although container is created with non-root user

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

### Description

I am conducting some `pytest` on a container which should do the following checks:

- check `/data` directory's ownership it should be `node-red:node-red`
- create a `/data/test.txt` within the `/data` directory and check its ownership (should be `node-red:node-red` (EDIT: this test passes)

I am achieving the above mentioned tasks using the python Docker SDK (4.10.0).

I initially spin up a Docker Compose stack and then conduct `pytest` on this stack. For the above mentioned tests I use `exec_run` which is equivalent to `docker exec` on the running node-red container.

#### Code

The following is the `test_perms.py`:

```py
# File: test_file_perms.py
# Desc: Tests for Filesystem Ownership within the Node-RED Container

import docker
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def exec_container():
    """Fixture to return the container `my-node-red` for exec processes
       in tests
    """
    client = docker.from_env()
    return client.containers.get('my-node-red')


def test_data_dir_ownership(exec_container):
    """Container Exec: File System Ownership
    Test: Ownership for '/data' directory should be 'nodered:nodered'"""
    # This test fails!!!
    exec_cont_result = exec_container.exec_run('stat -c "%U:%G" /data', user='node-red')
    assert exec_cont_result.exit_code == 0
    assert exec_cont_result.output  == b'node-red:node-red\n'


def test_file_creation_ownership(exec_container):
    """Container Exec: File Creation and Ownership Check
    Test: Should Create file '/data/test.txt'
          Ownership of '/data/test.txt' should be 'nodered:nodered'"""
    # This test PASSES
    exec_cont_result = exec_container.exec_run(cmd='touch /data/test.txt', user='node-red')
    assert exec_cont_result.exit_code == 0
    exec_cont_result = exec_container.exec_run('stat -c "%U:%G" /data/test.txt')
    assert exec_cont_result.exit_code == 0
    assert exec_cont_result.output  == b'node-red:node-red\n'
```

The tests pass successfully on my local machine (Window 10 Windows Subsystem for Linux 2)

### CI/CD Infrastructure

I have a self-hosted **GitLab-CE** instance and the runners are configured for docker-in-docker (dind)

Upon bringing the stack up in the `dind` Runner, I get the following failure

```
___________________________ test_data_dir_ownership ____________________________
exec_container = <Container: 21aed1f168>
    def test_data_dir_ownership(exec_container):
        """Container Exec: File System Ownership
        Test: Ownership for '/data' directory should be 'nodered:nodered'"""
        exec_cont_result = exec_container.exec_run('stat -c "%U:%G" /data', user='node-red')
        assert exec_cont_result.exit_code == 0
>       assert exec_cont_result.output  == b'node-red:node-red\n'
E       AssertionError: assert b'node-red:root\n' == b'node-red:node-red\n'
E         At index 9 diff: b'r' != b'n'
E         Full diff:
E         - b'node-red:node-red\n'
E         ?            ^ ^^^^^^
E         + b'node-red:root\n'
E         ?            ^ ^^
tests/test_file_perms.py:22: AssertionError
```

It states that the Group ownership of the `/data` (using `stat -c "%U:%G" /data`) is `root` and not `node-red`.

How is this possible? Is there something I should be configuring somewhere that I might have missed out?

```
default:
  image: docker:20.10.17
  tags: ["dind"]
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.docker
    - cp $DOCKER_AUTH  ~/.docker/config.json
services:
  - name: docker:20.10.17-dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=personl.artifactory.com", "--tls=false"]

variables:
  DOCKER_REGISTRY: personal.artifactory.com
  DOCKER_REPOSITORY: docker_edgest
  DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
  DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""


stages:
  - Build
  - Test
  - Deploy

build:
  stage: Build
  script:
    - sh ci/build.sh

tests:
  stage: Test
  needs:
    - build
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.17-dind
      command: ["--insecure-registry=personal.artifactory.com", "--tls=false"]
      alias: localhost
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.docker
    - cp $DOCKER_AUTH  ~/.docker/config.json
    - sh ci/prepare.sh
  script:
    - sh ci/test_run.sh
  after_script:
    - sh ci/test_teardown.sh

deploy:
  stage: Deploy
  interruptible: true
  only:
    - tags
  script:
    - sh ci/deploy.sh
```

### Edit

`Dockerfile` for Image

```
FROM nodered/node-red:2.2.2 as build

# Install necessary node-red Nodes via package.json
COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --unsafe-perm --no-update-notifier --no-audit --only=production

FROM build as prod
USER node-red

# Copy assets to `/data` directory
COPY --chown=node-red:node-red ./data /data

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

the `/data` directory is generally provided in the base image of `nodered/node-red`

Comment: You are creating the text file from inside the container using the correct user. The directory is created elsewhere, i'm assuming /data is created by root and therefore owned by root. How and when is the directory created? If you would run exec_cont_result = exec_container.exec_run(cmd='mkdir /data/test', user='node-red') and check the owner of that dir it will be node-red

Comment: @IdsvanderZee `/data` is already part of the base `nodered/node-red` image. All I do is just copy some files and assets to this dedicated `/data`. I will update the query with the `Dockerfile` for more clarity

Comment: The folders created by the base image are owned by root. using COPY with --chown only changes ownership of the files you copy not the ownership of the folder you copy to.